# Visual Studio Code snippet for doxygen style comments

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is there a snippet/extension that allows me to highlight multiple lines of text and using a key bind, to prepend the doxygen style characters `///` in front of them, just like `ctrl+/` does for C/C++ comments?
This would be really helpful.

Comment: Might there be blank lines within the range of selected text?

Comment: Yes, there can be blank lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have multiple selections it is as easy as this keybinding:

```
{
  "key": "alt+w",
  "command": "editor.action.insertSnippet",
  "args": {
    "snippet": "/// ${TM_SELECTED_TEXT}"  
  },
  "when": "editorHasMultipleSelections && textInputFocus"
},
```

---

Comment: This is good, but I would like it to behave more like the C comment keybind, meaning it should move the cursor to the beginning of the line, then prepend the ```///``` characters, even I have multiple lines selected, only one, etc. Yours just appends the characters only if multiple cursors, and is not that fun when I have 50 lines of code and have to set multiple cursors with ```alt``` key.

Comment: @Justplayit Use the keybinding Ctrl+Alt+Keydown to add a new multicursor

Comment: In this conditions, it works like a charm, but you know what I really want :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the extension [Regex Text Generator](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.regex-text-gen).

Select the lines/text you want to comment with multi cursor and then apply the keybinding.

Add the following keybinding

```
  {
    "key": "ctrl+f7",  // or any other key combo
    "when": "editorTextFocus",
    "command": "regexTextGen.generateText",
    "args": {
      "generatorRegex" : "/// {{0}}"
    }
  }
```

---

In version 0.9.0 of the `Regex Text Generator` extension I have added the possibility to use parts of the first selected line.

With the following keybinding you can use the whitespace part on the first selected line and determine the indentation of the comment characters:

```
  {
    "key": "ctrl+f7",  // or any other key combo
    "when": "editorTextFocus",
    "command": "regexTextGen.generateText",
    "args": {
      "originalTextRegex": "([ \\t]*)(.*)",
      "generatorRegex" : "{{1:first}}/// {{1:-first}}{{2}}"
    }
  }
```

Also empty lines will now be indented correct.

You might need to use `Trim Trailing Whitespace` (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>)

How to select the lines to comment:

- go to the start of the first line, column 1
- add additional cursors with: `Add Cursor Below` <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>DownArrow</kbd>
- select the complete lines: <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>End</kbd>
- call the defined keybinding: here <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>
- exit multi cursor mode: <kbd>Esc</kbd>

It is not much different compared to block selection <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>DownArrow</kbd>. And once you get happy with multi cursor you wonder how you could have done without it.

Just read a VSC multi cursor trick from [Justin Grant](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63928719/9938317) in creating a multi cursor selection with the mouse and modifier keys <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>. For really large numbers of lines this could be handy.

Comment: This one behaves strange, instead of appending ```///```, it just generates a random sequence of ```a```, ```b```, and ```c``` characters.

Comment: @Justplayit A string of random `abc` is the default value of the `generatorRegex` property. Then you have an error in the `args` part of the keybinding, it must be an object `{}` with properties, and the case of the property name is important. And in the original answer I copied a `}` too short.

Comment: If I select multiple lines, it will only keep the first line and prepend ```///``` to it. I need it for all lines, if possible.

Comment: @Justplayit I have modified the extension and now it handles the indentation correct, see the updated keybinding

Comment: Still using only the first line if multiple lines are selected.

Comment: @Justplayit Then you do not have a multi cursor selection, you have 1 selection with multiple lines. You need to have **each** line in it's own selection. You need to use `Add Cursor Below`, `Alt-Mouse_click` or Justin Grant's method of getting multiple cursors