# In VSCode, how can I turn a multi-line comment into a paragraph with no line breaks?

Tags: visual-studio-code, multiple-cursor

What's an easy way to convert a multi-line comment (e.g. JSDoc with each line separated by line breaks) into a paragraph without any line breaks that I can copy into an email or another document?

I know I can use search & replace with regular expressions, but is there a more ergonomic way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

You probably knew that you can use multiple cursors to change multiple lines at once, but did you know you can also use them to remove line breaks? Assume you start with this comment:

````js
  /**
   * Returns a new `Temporal.LocalDateTime` instance representing the first
   * valid time during the current calendar day and time zone of `this`.
   *
   * The local time of the result is almost always `00:00`, but in rare cases it
   * could be a later time e.g. if DST starts at midnight in a time zone. For
   * example:
   * ```
   * const ldt = Temporal.LocalDateTime.from('2015-10-18T12:00-02:00[America/Sao_Paulo]');
   * ldt.startOfDay; // => 2015-10-18T01:00-02:00[America/Sao_Paulo]
   * ```
   */
````

First part: use multiple cursors to remove the prefix characters on each line.

- Click on the upper-left corner of the comment (the   `/**`).
- Now hold down Cmd+Shift (Alt+Shift on PC) and click after the    `*/` on the last line of the comment section.
- This will create a columnar, multi-line selection that includes the non-text prefix characters on each line.  If the selection doesn't include all the prefix characters, you can hold down the Shift key and use the left or right arrow keys to adjust the width of the selection.
- Press the Delete key to remove prefix characters on all lines.

Second part: it's time to delete the line breaks and replace them with spaces. I discovered today that you can use multiple cursors for this part too!

- After you've deleted the prefix text above, but before you've pressed any other keys, press the backspace key. It will delete the line breaks but leave each cursor in the same place!
- Type the spacebar once to insert one space to replace each line break.
- Press ESC to clear multiple selections, and delete the extra space at the start of the line. You may have an extra space(s) at the end of the line too that may need trimming.
- Copy the resulting one-line text.
- Use Cmd+Z (Ctrl+Z on Windows) to undo the last few changes so your code comment will be back to normal.
- Now you can paste the copied text into an email!

The same solution works to replace line breaks with spaces in any multi-line text, not only code comments.

I'm sure that many of you already knew how to do this trick, but I found it so easy and so cool that I thought it was worth sharing as a Q&A here so others can learn about this trick too.

Here's what the steps look like in the VSCode IDE:

Before deleting, you should see something like this:
[image]

After deleting prefix characters:
[image]

After deleting line breaks (note the multiple cursors are still there):
[image]

After inserting spaces in place of the deleted line breaks:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I usually select the first line break, then hit/hold `command+D` repeatedly to add cursors at all line endings I want to edit. Then, just hit space once.